# Gatsby CMS - Failed to load settings from /.netlify/identity

Tags: gatsby, netlify, netlify-cms

I've installed gastby 2 on an ubuntu 16.04 box

```
gatsby new netlifycms2 https://github.com/netlify-templates/gatsby-starter-netlify-cms
```

without error.

However when I visit /admin and click **login with netlify** I get the message

**Failed to load settings from /.netlify/identity**

I assume I need this file but haven't found any instructions as how to install it.

I manually added a blank identity file in **static/admin/.netlify/identity** then ran gatsby build and gatsby serve however the error message persists

I've done some reading on [authentication and backends](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/authentication-backends/) this [blog](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2017/09/07/introducing-built-in-identity-service-to-streamline-user-management/) which suggests:

“Once you enable Identity services, a managed version of the GoTrue microservice lets you add user registration and management under /.netlify/identity for any Netlify site.”

I note the gotrue cms.js is installed in the admin directory and a few others

```
./public/admin/cms.js
./node_modules/netlify-cms/dist/cms.js
./node_modules/gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms/cms.js
./src/cms/cms.js
```

Is there is a bug with the netlify identity plugin that this file is not created?

```
 System:
    OS: Linux 4.4 Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (Xenial Xerus)
    CPU: x64 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v4 @ 2.20GHz
    Shell: 4.3.48 - /bin/bash
  Binaries:
    Node: 10.10.0 - /usr/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.9.4 - /usr/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.4.1 - /usr/bin/npm
  npmPackages:
    gatsby: ^2.0.0 => 2.0.1 
    gatsby-plugin-netlify: ^2.0.0 => 2.0.0 
    gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms: ^3.0.0 => 3.0.1 
    gatsby-plugin-react-helmet: ^3.0.0 => 3.0.0 
    gatsby-plugin-sass: ^2.0.1 => 2.0.1 
    gatsby-plugin-sharp: ^2.0.5 => 2.0.5 
    gatsby-remark-images: ^2.0.1 => 2.0.1 
    gatsby-source-filesystem: ^2.0.1 => 2.0.1 
    gatsby-transformer-remark: ^2.1.1 => 2.1.2 
    gatsby-transformer-sharp: ^2.1.1 => 2.1.1 
  npmGlobalPackages:
    gatsby-cli: 2.4.1
```

Additionally I've cloned the https://github.com/netlify-templates/gatsby-starter-netlify-cms into gitlab however I get the same issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Gatsby [starter](https://github.com/netlify-templates/gatsby-starter-netlify-cms) uses `git-gateway` backend for `netlify-cms` and expects to be hosted on the Netlify and have Netlify Identity service enabled. The Gatsby Starter project is one of the one-click templates.

```
backend:
  name: git-gateway
  branch: master
```

Netlify uses [GoTrue](https://github.com/netlify/gotrue) open-source API written in golang, that can act as a self-standing API service for handling user registration and authentication.

[GoTrue](https://github.com/netlify/gotrue) is not part of the NetlifyCMS app bundle (netlify-cms.js or cms.js). When you enable identity on a Netlify site, there is an API endpoint created on the site for the `/.netlify/identity` 
 endpoint. Adding an endpoint without the GoTrue API is not going to be valid.

### Git-Gateway Option

Host the Gatsby/NetlifyCMS site on Netlify and enable [Netlify Identity service](https://www.netlify.com/docs/identity/) through the site's admin on `app.netlify.com` and continue to use `git-gateway`.

### Self Host using GitLab

Self host your site and change the `config.yml` to use the GitLab backend and use [implicit grant setup](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/authentication-backends/#client-side-implicit-grant)

### Use your own OAuth

Self host your site and change the `config.yml` to use the GitHub backend and [use your own OAuth authentication](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/authentication-backends/#external-oauth-clients)